# How do I set a timer for a image to appear in javascript or html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer, facebook-iframe

Currently I have the following piece of code but it isn't working on my facebook iframe application.

```
function Timer(){
    document.getElementById('buybtn').style.visibility = "visible"; 
    setTimeout(Timer,1080000);
}
```

and the following html:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">'</p>
<div id="buybtn">
   <p style="text-align:center">
      <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
         <img src="http://www.adspecialist.be/wp-content/themes/adspecialist/img/visit-my-website-en.png" border="0" />
       </a>
   </p>
</div>
```

Could you please let me know how to fix this problem

Comment: What do you mean it isn't working?  Are you waiting for the required 18 minutes?

Comment: The value you have in setTimeout looks very long....try reducing to 5000 (5 seconds) to check more easily

Comment: The problem is that I can see it. Not that I cannot see it.

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not supposed to work, because `Timer()` will never be called since you have your timeout *inside* the function. Move it outside and it will work.

```
function Timer(){
    document.getElementById('buybtn').style.visibility = "visible"; 
}

setTimeout(Timer,3000);
```

[demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4b5k/)

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks a lot